# How to use square brackets in grep for MINGW64?

Tags: regex, windows, bash, grep, mingw-w64

Currently, I have a following regex. It should match a string that I am echoing:

```
echo "TBGFSGFI22800_D_REP_D_RISIKOEINHEIT" | grep -E 'TBGFSGFI\d\d\d\d\d[A-Za-z_]{1,100}'
```

It works as expected in OsX on my Mac and in Notepad++, but in Bash for windows (MINGW64) I get an empty string. How can I use the grep with flags, or how should I rewrite the regex to match the pattern?

My grep version is 3.1. Bash: 4.4.23(1)

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: `\d` is not actually a valid POSIX ERE construct, use `-P` instead of `-E`.

Comment: Thanks, the following works: echo `"TBGFSGFI22800_D_REP_D_RISIKOEINHEIT" | grep -Poz 'TBGFSGFI\d\d\d\d\d[A-Za-z_]{1,100}'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you answer the question instead of comment? I will mark it as an answer :)

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a POSIX ERE regex with the `-E` option, and that flavor does not support `\d` construct. You also need `-o` option to actually extract the matches.

Note you do not need to repeat `\d` five times, you can use a range quantifier, `\d{5}`.

You can use

```sh
echo "TBGFSGFI22800_D_REP_D_RISIKOEINHEIT" | grep -Po "TBGFSGFI\d{5}[A-Za-z_]{1,100}"
```

Where

- `-P` means the regex is of a PCRE flavor
- `-o` extracts matches only
- `TBGFSGFI\d{5}[A-Za-z_]{1,100}` - a regex that matches `TBGFSGFI`, then any five digits and then 1-100 ASCII letters or `_`.